# Using IN clause with CSV cell value to map with a smallint column in another table

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, csv

I have a table where cells have values stored as CSV (like `2,4,5,6,7`). This is basically CSV for months applicable in some criteria, so I have to map those with the actual month ids in my **MonthMaster**

Let's say my CSV Column's Name in one table is `ApplicableMonthIDs` having value `3,4,5,6`(no spaces in between)

And, I have MonthMaster Table where there are MonthID and MonthNames

```
MonthID    MonthName
3          March
4          April
5          May
6          June
-          ---
```

I have a query where I have to return the values of `ApplicableMonthIDs` which was `3,4,5,6` as `March,April,May,June`

Here is what I tried (I have to use this as a sub-query, with multiple joins and cases so, simple would better)

```
Select Stuff((Select ',' + MonthName  from MonthMaster where convert(varchar(10), MonthID) in (Replace(ApplicableMonthIDs ,',',''',''')) for XML Path('')),1,1,'')
```

Note that `ApplicableMonthIDs` is a `varchar` column and `MonthID` is `smallint`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try out below script

> DECLARE @MonthMaster TABLE  (   ID INT PRIMARY KEY,    Months
>   VARCHAR(32) NOT NULL UNIQUE );
>
> DECLARE @MonthsMapping TABLE (   ID INT PRIMARY KEY,    Name
>   NVARCHAR(64) NOT NULL,   ApplicableMonthIDs VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL );
>
> INSERT @MonthMaster VALUES    (1,'jan'),  (2,'feb'),  (3,'march');
>
> INSERT @MonthsMapping VALUES   (1,'aa','2,1'), (2,'bbb','1'),
>   (3,'ccc','1,3'),  (4,'dd','2,3,1');
>
> SELECT ID, Name, ApplicableMonthIDs = STUFF((SELECT ',' + d.Months 
>       FROM @MonthMaster AS d
>       INNER JOIN @MonthsMapping AS ei
>       ON ',' + ei.ApplicableMonthIDs + ',' LIKE '%,' + CONVERT(VARCHAR(12), d.id) + ',%'
>       WHERE ei.ID = e.ID
>       ORDER BY d.id
>       FOR XML PATH, TYPE).value('.[1]', 'nvarchar(max)'), 1, 1, '') FROM @MonthsMapping AS e ORDER >BY ID;

I think this will help you

Answer (score 0):

Try out below query..

> declare @ApplicableMonthIDs varchar(50) set @ApplicableMonthIDs
>   ='2,3,4,7'
>
> EXEC (' SELECT * FROM [dbo].[MonthMaster] WHERE CONVERT(VARCHAR(50),MonthID) IN
>   ( ' + @ApplicableMonthIDs + ' ) ') GO

the above query is faster as it used a Clustered Index Seek only.

Comment: I guess, this does not return the result in required form i.e. `April,May,June`